# Knitting error on Mac because of windowsFonts()

Tags: r, r-markdown

A friend of mine sent me an R Markdown document to work on. He works on Windows, I work on Mac.
Now, when I try to Knit to PDF, I get the following error (sorry if this is not exactly what it would say in an English version of R, translated from German):

```
Error in windowsFonts(Times = windowsFont("Times New Roman")) : could not find function "windowsFonts".
```

I read somewhere that this windowsFonts function works on Windows only. Is there a way to circumvent this error?